# Using Paypal Cordova Plugin, cannot get it to work using production or sandbox mode

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, paypal

I am getting this error when I switch to sandbox mode using the cordova paypal plugin, located here https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Cordova-Plugin

[image]

When I run this plugin using the PayPalEnvironmentNoNetwork mode, everything works perfectly as I intended. I set up a classic payapl api app and put in the correct production id and sandbox id, but it does not seem to want to work with those is there something I am missing?

I have never used PayPal's api before so I am not quite sure what I am doing, just trying to set up a simple donation flow in my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a rest paypal api app, not classic since the cordova sdk is built on top of the mobile sdks which calls the rest apis. This should be helpful to get started https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/make-your-first-call/